# Django 2 schedulers being run

Tags: django

These are my files-

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        import api.scheduler as scheduler
        scheduler.start()
```

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def fetch_new_raw_data():
    '''Fetches new data'''

def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(fetch_new_raw_data, 'interval', minutes=1)
    scheduler.start()
    fetch_new_raw_data()
```

When using `py manage.py runserver` django spawns 2 processes, each one will start a scheduler.
Is there a way to load up the scheduler only in 1 process and use the same in both or is it ok for them to start their own scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

In production mode or debug mode, this class is initialized multiple times. this solution is not working very well, but you can record `os.getpid()` result in a file or DB record and check it every time. If PID is changed you start scheduler again.

```py
import os
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api'

    def ready(self):
        pid = os.getpid()
        with open("/path/to/log/api_pid", "r") as pid_file:
            if pid_file.read().strip() == pid:
                return
        with open("/path/to/log/api_pid", "w") as pid_file:
            pid_file.write(pid)
        import api.scheduler as scheduler
            scheduler.start()
```

But I recommend you to use external services like [celery project](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) or use [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it after runing the project.

Comment: Why would the class be initialized multiple times? You mean multiple processes would initialize it or 1 process would initialize it multiple times?

Comment: Django project is running in the multiprocess runner. Sometimes processes are destroyed or multi processes are initialized. I test it and use both solutions. I think never re initialize a module but it may be done in django!

Comment: So, if multiple processes are initialized then would they need their own scheduler?

Comment: if you want to be sure to run this code one time in each process, use it in the main `urls.py` or use this PID lock.